# Apple Watch interaction with Home Screen

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xctest, homescreen, xcuitest

I am automating Apple Watch ui testing and currently I stuck with the problem interacting with Apple Watch Home Screen (e.g. tap, press, scroll, etc.)
I know that testing is happening in the sandbox of the app under test, but I need to interact with the elements on Home Screen when the app under test is running on the background.
I know that Appium does similar thing to iPhone's Home Screen via "com.apple.springboard" which is the app, that manages iPhone's Home Screen, but what about Apple Watch? Is there a way I can interact with Apple Watch Home Screen?

Answer (score 0):

Per the other question you have open regarding the iOS home screen, the watch can be interacted with the following bundle identifiers:

`com.apple.BackBoard`, `com.apple.BaseBoardUI`, `com.apple.PreBoard`, and `com.apple.ReBoard`.

The following debug command should show you what's available for interaction:

```
po XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifer: "oneOfThoseBundleIDs")
```

Comment: Hi, Mike! 
I tried all of those ids, but there is no matching existing application that comes by them
**for exemple**
`let homescreenApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.ReBoard")`
`po homescreenApp.exists` returns `false`
as every id from the list

Comment: Sorry to hear that didn’t work. I’d suggest opening an Apple support ticket then.

Comment: Yes, I already created one and I am waiting for the response from Apple, will keep you posted and thank you!